# View.post vs runnable.run

Tags: android, view

I have Compound View (`ConstraintLayout`). Sometimes this View can change its size, and I need change visibility of several views inside parent view.

I do it inside callback `onSizeChanged()`. If I do it simple, like this:

```
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        configurator.constraint()
    }
```

sometimes views doesn't change their visibilty. It can happens quite randomly.

But, if I do it with `post{}` or `doOnPreDraw{}`

```
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        doOnPreDraw { configurator.constraint() }
    }
```

everything is OK.

I want understand why it's happens. What difference between this to approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSizeChanged()` is not called on the main thread, and any updates from other threads to UI are not guaranteed. Synchronizing back to the main thread via `post()` or `doOnPreDraw()` fix the issue as you have observed.